# Get back empty array from MongoDB using curl although the database is filled up with data

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, curl, mean-stack

I am following the tutorial : https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial and adapting it to a side project to get a better understanding of how the mean stack works.

I have created a data base and imported a json into it using mongoimport : `mongoimport --db cmt2 --collection Course --type json --file myFile.json --jsonArray`

I have declared my database using : `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cmt2');`

When I curl my server after starting it with npm start : `curl http://localhost:3000/courses` I only get an empty array in return ( [] ).

But I am sure I have imported the data into the db because when I go to mongo shell and open the cmt2 database and use `db.Course.find()` I get back all my data.

My get route for courses is also probably correct since it works when I define another db I used for testing before I used cmt2 : `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/cmt');`

It's probably something stupid about collection I don't understand because I name them randomly and I have no idea where I actually declare which collection I want to work with in my code.

For reference, here is the code I use for my get request :

```
router.get('/courses', function(req, res, next) {
  Course.find(function(err, courses){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(courses);
  });
});
```

And an example of the data in the json I have imported in the db :

```
{
        "code": "ABCD ",
        "name": "ABCDE",
        "list": [
            {
                "code": "ABCDEF ",
                "name": "ABCDEFG"
            },
            {
                "code": "BCDEF ",
                "name": "BCDEFG"
            }]
}
```

EDIT :

The major difference between cmt (the database I can curl) and cmt2 (the one i can't curl) is that I used embedded models with cmt and didn't with cmt2

Comment: Make your curl : `mongodb://localhost:27017/cmt`

And give an empty document as the first parameter to your `find` method. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was importing to the wrong localhost.